# Perfect complexes in non-semisimple group rings

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra

The study of non-commutative Iwasawa theory is using as tools algebraic K-theory and derived categories of perfect complex on group rings. By Maschke theorem, Let $G$ be a finite group and $K$ a field whose characteristic does not divide the order of $G$. Then $K[G]$ the group algebra is semisimple in particular projective modules are free and the notion of perfect complex is well understood. However when the group ring is not semisimple, the situation is more delicate. For example if $C$ is a complex $\mathbf{Z}_p[\mathbf{Z}/p]$ such that (1) $C$ is perfect as complex of $\mathbf Z_p$-modules and  (2) $C \otimes \mathbf{Q}_p$ is perfect as complex of $\mathbf{Q}_p[\mathbf{Z}/p]$. Does it implies that $C$ is a perfect complex of $\mathbf{Z}_p[\mathbf{Z}/p]$-module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be the complex with $\mathbf{Z}_p$ (with trivial action of $\mathbf{Z}/p$) in degree zero and zero in all other degrees.

Then $C$ is perfect as a complex of $\mathbf{Z}_p$-modules, but not as a complex of $\mathbf{Z}_p[\mathbf{Z}/p]$-modules, and $C\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}_p}\mathbf{Q}_p$ is perfect as a complex of $\mathbf{Q}_p[\mathbf{Z}/p]$-modules (since every bounded complex of finitely generated $\mathbf{Q}_p[\mathbf{Z}/p]$-modules is).

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: May I ask you an argument for C is not perfect as complex of $\mathbf{Z}_p[\mathbf{Z}/p]$-modules?

Comment: If it were perfect, then the cohomology $H^\ast(\mathbf{Z}/p,\mathbf{Z}_p)=\operatorname{Ext}^\ast_{\mathbf{Z}_p[\mathbf{Z}/p]}(\mathbf{Z}_p,\mathbf{Z}_p)$ would be zero in all but finitely many degrees.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for your kind explanation.